# Add two different fonts to the same button

Tags: css, html, fonts

I have a **button** and on it I want to add **two text labels** whose font and size differ. I also want each text label to appear on its own line. For example, if my labels are `ABCD` and `example`, here's how I want them to appear on the button:

**ABCD**
<sup>*example*</sup>

Here is what I have tried. Is it possible to apply different styles to different parts of the `value` attribute?

```html
<input style="width:170px; height:100px; font-size:90%; type="button" value="ABCD example">
```

Comment: i dont think you can

Comment: then is there any other way which can make it look like that?

Comment: use an image instead?

Comment: I dont have such image as of now.

Comment: just create one any free graphics program will be ine

Comment: You could create link/div that would have the style you want which, when clicked, would simulate a click on the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `button` rather than an `input` and use two `span` tags inside. For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    <span style="font-size:14px;">ABCD</span>
    <span style="font-size:10px;">example</span>
</button>
```

Live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/h6jq7ep2/

I've used inline styles just for simplicity, but obviously you could instead assign a `class` with the appropriate CSS to each `span`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `<button>` element:

```
<button><span style="font-size:110%">ABCD</span> example</button>
```

It works about the same was as `<input type="button">`

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this, you want to apply style on a part of the  string, there is no simple way of doing this, you should use image instead. the is pure design purpose.  just search online button image maker, you'll find a lot.